# dividing system.collections.bitarray into sub bitarrays of 32 bits each

Tags: c#, .net

I have searched in net but not getting exactly what I need.
I have a bitarray of size 15,936. I need to divide this bit array into list of bitarrays , with each bit array having 32 bits(15936/32 = 498 bitarray list).

Not able to find exactly how to divide bitarray. Please do help.

Thanks,

Comment: You  could always use an `int[498]`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first that you want 32-bit values makes this pretty easy, because you can copy it to an `int[]`, then create one `BitArray` per `int`, passing the data by creating a single-element `int` array:

```
int[] values = new int[bigBitArray.Length / 32];
bigBitArray.CopyTo(values, 0);
var smallBitArrays = values.Select(v => new BitArray(new[] { v })).ToList();
```

Or more efficiently, reusing the same `int[]` for each iteration:

```
int[] values = new int[bigBitArray.Length / 32];
bigBitArray.CopyTo(values, 0);
// Reuse this on every iteration, to avoid creating more arrays than we need.
// Somewhat ugly, but more efficient.
int[] buffer = new int[1];
var smallBitArrays = values.Select(v =>
{ 
    buffer[0] = v; 
    return new BitArray(buffer))
}).ToList();
```

If those give you the bit arrays in the opposite order to what you expect, just call `Array.Reverse(values)` after the `CopyTo` call.

It's a pity that `BitArray` doesn't have a constructor taking an existing array, offset and count... that would make it significantly more efficient. (As would a "slice copy" operation, of course.)

A more general purpose option would be to create an extension method precisely for that "slice copy" part:

```
public static BitArray CopySlice(this BitArray source, int offset, int length)
{
    // Urgh: no CopyTo which only copies part of the BitArray
    BitArray ret = new BitArray(length);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
         ret[i] = source[offset + i];
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Then:

```
var smallBitArrays = Enumerable
    .Range(0, bigBitArray.Length / 32)
    .Select(offset => bigBitArray.CopySlice(offset * 32, 32))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This won't work because the `BitArray` constructor with an `int` param does not initialize the `BitArray`, it sets its capacity.

Comment: @Sefe: Have you seen the fix? (Not sure why this got a second downvote *after* fixing, but hey...)

Comment: @Sefe: Appreciated. Ah well - downvotes seem to have been removed now anyway. This question has reminded me what an awful API BitArray has :(

Comment: That's why I'm using Array.Copy. Even with an API, this would be the most efficient way to slice a bit array (it's how it would work under the hood, except it wouldn't need the CopyTo).

Comment: @Sefe: Why do you believe `Array.Copy` is more efficient than just `new int[] { v }`? If you'd used the same byte array for each iteration, that would be more efficient - something I'll do in my version now.

Comment: In this specific case Int32, is in fact more efficient. For arbitrary sizes I guess it would depend on the length of the sub-arrays. Sometimes a bit-by-bit copy would be more efficient (even though it would have to do quite a few bitwise operations), in other cases the memcpy involved with Array.Copy. The problem in my solution is only the initial Array.Copy, which is a bummer (whether it would be still more efficient in some constellations would be an interesting question).

Comment: hi, thanks for the response. bigBitArray.CopyTo(values, 0); is throwing exception "Destination array was not long enough. Check destIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds." any clues ?

Comment: @Naveenkumar: Are you sure your original BitArray's length is *exactly* a multiple of 32? My code would certainly fail if that's not the case.

Comment: @Jon Skeet : yes, I am getting int array of size 498, but copy is failing.

Comment: @Naveenkumar: Okay, will investigate.

Comment: @Naveenkumar: I can't reproduce the problem, I'm afraid. When I have a bit array of length 15936, it's not throwing an exception. Can you create a [mcve] in a gist?

Comment: @JonSkeet : hi, sorry, my bad.  your code is working fine. thanks :)

Comment: @JonSkeet : hi , I came across a point that "BitArray stores bits in reverse order when initialized with an Int32 array". I am sure about this, but is this affect the above code in any manner, if so could you explain how and why ??

Comment: @Naveenkumar: I don't know whether it's affecting your code or not - I don't know what your expected result is. That sounds like something you should be looking into yourself. (It's easily fixed by reversing the `int` array after copying.)

Comment: @JonSkeet : I want the bits to be copied in same order of big array into small arrays. Just not sure what that statement means..

Comment: Well if you don't understand your own requirements, I'm afraid I can't help you with them. You should be able to see whether my code works for you or not. If it doesn't, I suspect that calling `Array.Reverse(values)` after the `CopyTo` call will fix it.

Comment: @JonSkeet : I understand my requirement , I dint understand the statement  "BitArray stores bits in reverse order when initialized with an Int32 array". Anyway , thanks for your fix :)

Answer (score 1):

You can copy your bit array into an array of bytes, split that array into chunks and create new bit arrays:

```
const int subArraySizeBits = 32;
const int subArraySizeBytes = subArraySizeBits / 8;
byte[] bitData = new byte[myBitArray.Length / subArraySizeBytes];
myBitArray.CopyTo(bitData, 0);
List<BitArray> result = new List<BitArray>();
for (int index = 0; index < bitData.Length; index += subArraySizeBytes) {
    byte[] subData = new byte[subArraySizeBytes];
    Array.Copy(bitData, index * subArraySizeBytes, subData, 0, subArraySizeBytes);
    result.Add(new BitArray(subData));
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the response, I also thought to do in this way. yours is a good answer too.