# How to extract set of bits from BitArray in C#?

Tags: c#, bitarray

For eg.

```
uint Data= 0x91ADC800;
BitArray myBitArray = new BitArray(BitConverter.GetBytes(Data));
BitArray ExtractArray;//This should have data from 20th bit to 31st bit
```

I tried BitArray.Copyto(..) Which copies entire bit array to single 1D array in specified index.
I tried Array.Copy(..) which copies from one array to another array.
My intention is to fetch the given set of index(say 20th to 31st) from the array.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `BitConverter.GetBytes(Data).Skip(19).Take(12).ToArray()`?

Comment: Jon's [`CopySlice`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41035735/dividing-system-collections-bitarray-into-sub-bitarrays-of-32-bits-each) [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) in the linked question (above) should do the trick for you.